# How to write authenticationManager as a bean (Converting SamlAuthenticationManager to bean)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am implementing Spring SAML in my web app which already has spring security implemented, due to which I have 2 authentication managers now. As spring always refer to the last declared authenticationManager, I found the solution to define one authenticationManager as a bean.

Following was my AuthenticationManager before conversion to bean:

```
<authentication-manager alias="samlAuthenticationManager">
    <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
    <authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <!-- Register authentication manager for administration UI -->
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="adminInterfaceService">
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Following is my code after converting to bean:

```
<beans:bean id="samlAuthenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:property name="userDetails" value="adminInterfaceService"/>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
<user-service id="adminInterfaceService">
    <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</user-service>
```

Authentication provider is defines as follows:

```
<beans:bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
        <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login -->
        <!--
        <beans:property name="userDetails" ref="bean" />
        -->
</beans:bean>
```

I am getting following exception:

> Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'org.springframework.security.saml.userdetails.SAMLUserDetailsService'
>   for property 'userDetails'

Please help regarding the same. I will be highly obliged.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2163

Just had to use id instead of alias in both the authentication-manager

> You shouldn't need to use Spring beans. If you don't specify an ID,
>   you will override the "default" instance. That's pretty much the way
>   standard Spring beans work. In the referenced thread, the user is
>   specifying an alias, rather than an ID, so that doesn't create a
>   separate instance. Again that's the way normal bean instances work, so
>   I'm not sure we should deviate from that.